# What could cause my program to only read 2 lines of a 3 line input

Tags: c++11

I have a program that is supposed to take in a paragraph like

```
Testing#the hash#tag
#program!#when #beginning? a line
or #also a #comma,
```

and output something like

```
#the
#tag
#program
#when
#beginning
#also
#comma,
```

I feel like the logic makes sense, but obviously not because the program never seems to get into the line of input. The problem is almost definitely in the last source file below.

Here is the main source program

```
#include "HashTagger.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace hw02;
using namespace std;

int main() {

  // Construct an object for extracting the
  // hashtags.

  HashTagger hashTagger;

  // Read the standard input and extract the
  // hashtags.

  while (true) {

    // Read one line from the standard input.

    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    if (!cin) {
      break;
    }

    // Get all of the hashtags on the line.

    hashTagger.getTags(line);
  }

  // Print the hashtags.

  hashTagger.printTags();

  // Return the status.

  return 0;
}
```

my header file

```
#ifndef HASHTAGGER_H
#define HASHTAGGER_H

#include <string>

namespace hw02 {

class HashTagger {
public:
    void getTags(std::string line);

    void printTags();

private:

    std::string hashtags_;

};

}

#endif
```

and a source file
the test in the source file seems to show that the program only gets to the second line and then stops before grabbing the last 2 hashtags

```
#include "HashTagger.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace hw02;

void HashTagger::getTags(string line) {

    // Loop over all characters in a line that can begin a hashtag
    int b = 0;
    string hashtags_ = "";
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < line.length(); ++j) {
        char c = line.at(j);

        // if "#" is found assign beginning of capture to b
        if (c == '#') {
            b = j;

            // if the beginning is less than the end space, newline, ".", "?", or "!" found, add substring of the hashtag to hashtags_
        }
        if (b < j && (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!' )) {
            hashtags_ = hashtags_ + "\n" + line.substr(b, j - b + 1);
            b = 0;
            //Test// cout << b << "/" << j << "/" << c <<  "/" << hashtags_ << "/" <<  endl;
        }
    }
}

void HashTagger::printTags() {

    // print out hashtags_ to the console
    cout << hashtags_ << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redeclaring `hashtags_` inside your `getTags` function. Therefore, all string modifications operate on a local variable instead of the class member variable.

Change the line

`string hashtags_ = "";`

to

`hashtags_ = "";`

in order to avoid the redeclaration and operate on the class member variable used for the output later on.

---

Also, make sure that your input is terminated with two newline characters (`\n\n`), to avoid `break`ing out of the main loop too early, or move your check and `break` statement after the `getTags` call:

```
  while (true) {

    // Read one line from the standard input.
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    // Get all of the hashtags on the line.
    hashTagger.getTags(line);

    if (!cin) {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: good catch and quick question. Does the string stored in hashtags_ ever make it to the printTags() to be called? I ask because the output is blank  for the main program and the only output I can get is from the getTags method.

Comment: If you remove the redeclaration, then yes, it will. You then operate on the member variable of the object, and since you are calling `getTags` and `printTags` on the same object, the string will "carry over".

Comment: @Vyff I added a possible cause for your third line to never be processed.

Comment: for the problem, we are not allowed to change the Main executable. Though I tried what you suggested, it still wasn't working for me. I believe it is a bug somewhere else in the code, because it wont work for just the first line of the input either. perhaps it is something with my IDE Eclipse.

Comment: you taught me about input files today instead of copy paste into the console and for that I thank you. Still pretty broken, but you answered my question with the line of thinking.